# Restore innodb from *.ibd - text fields

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

I have success with restoring *.ibd with short text fields, but when I try page_parser with big ibd file it's give me just 16kb file.

I used percona recovery tool. As I understood long text contains in indexes FTS_00000.........idb

How I can restore it? For now I have table scheme from frm, and full set of *.ibd with all FTS_xxx files.

Tried alter table xxx discard tablespace and then put *.ibd and doing import tablespace, but mysql crashes. It can't import index ibd's?

Comment: Hi there, this is likely a better fit on https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: See if this helps https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16875/restore-table-from-frm-and-ibd-file

Comment: I saw this, as I said it's not helped (